# how does a lexer differentiate the ':','::', and ':=' tokens from each other?

Tags: lexer

S++ uses ':' as the type specification operation and also to map keys to values in dictionaries,'::' as concatenation, and ':=' as assignment. All share the prefix ':'.

1) how does a lexer differentiate the ':','::', and ':=' tokens from each other?

2) how does a lexer differentiate the two uses of ':' ?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** This is basic lexical analysis. Once you see the `:` you know it could be one of a few symbols so you need to look at the next character before you can resolve what you've got.

**2.** It doesn't. It just says we've got a DOUBLE_COLON token. The next step (parser) will decide what the DOUBLE_COLON means.